# Android stuck on roaming mode

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, mobile-data, roaming

I own a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 (SM-N900), with Android 4.4.2 installed on it.
It was purchased through Partner (Israel) and I have recently moved to Germany for work.

Upon my arrival, I purchased a SIM card from a carrier called Lycamobile and I regularly top up my account per demand.

**Problem** - the device is stuck on roaming mode.

**What I've done so far:**

1. I toggled *Data Roaming* in the *More Networks* -->*Mobile Networks* menu; when enabled, the device is set on Roaming Mode automatically (see figure #1).
   [image: figure #1]
2. When *Data Roaming* is disabled, mobile data is disabled, too (see figure #2).
   [image: figure #2]
3. Taking the SIM card in and out several times hasn't helped much (I've see that it helped Verizon users in the US in some forums online).
4. I manually changed the carrier to my carrier (*Lycamobile*) instead of letting the device choose one automatically.

Now, the mobile data works as I'm obviously not roaming, but it doesn't work great and I also have to be on roaming mode enabled, which is simply wrong.

Is any one familiar with this behaviour? Thanks in advance for the helpers.

Comment: Based on your action of switching SIMs I assume your phone is not in a contract. In that case, can you try using the LycaMobile SIM in some other mobile and use some other SIM (one from Lyca and one from another) in your Note 3. This is to rule out SIM based issues.

Comment: Great idea, will give it a shot today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find it hard to believe, but the only thing that helped my peculiar case was **moving to another carrier**!

Needless to say, I did not leave the carrier (Lycamobile Germany) for this reason, I left it because they had bad service and a bad product.

Again, nothing helped, nor did the carrier's finest technical advisers could determine why this was happening.

So here's to 7 months of roaming coming to an end.

Answer (score 0):

Try Switching your network mode to manual head over to the Settings>Under wirless and networks> tap more settings>Mobile Networks> Network operator> Search for the Network again now after searching select the appropriate network. This keeps happening with my device too there are actually two Mobile Networks, it usually arises because you may be living in border and somehow the signals from other Lycan network, I am sure you are doing the same, I know its weird but I guess you can't help it its up to you carrier, you could give them a call about it.

Comment: Thanks, but choosing an operator manually is one of the things I've tried several times with no luck. 
Calling their call-center would probably be my last resort, given the fact that the probability of hitting an English speaking representative is very low here.

Comment: Well, in that case I would say try walking down their nearest store. I am sure their representatives can talk with you in english, and yes have you tried checking their site for the online support option (If they have?? )

Comment: Yup, they have a retailer nearby, I'll do that, too, thanks